# Difference between ftrace and strace in Linux

Tags: linux

both strace and ftrace seem to be used for tracing function calls in Linux. What's the difference?

Comment: man strace https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace .... man ftrace https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftrace

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 4):

`strace` is a utility which allows you to trace the system calls that an application makes. When an application makes a system call, it is basically asking the kernel to do something, eg file access. Use the command `man strace` to get `strace` documentation and `man syscalls` to get information on system calls.

`ftrace` is a tool used during kernel development and allows the developer to see what functions are being called within the kernel. The documentation is [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) and states:

> Ftrace is an internal tracer designed to help out developers and
>   designers of systems to find what is going on inside the kernel.
>   It can be used for debugging or analyzing latencies and
>   performance issues that take place outside of user-space.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.